# Get-SqlAgentJobHistory Invoked By

Tags: sql-server-agent, powershell

I want to report on failed Sql Agent jobs using Get-SqlAgentJobHistory but excluded jobs that were not invoked by the service account.
I'm running this cmd:

```
 Get-SqlAgentJobHistory -ServerInstance $SqlServer -OutcomesType Failed -StartRunDate ((Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15))
```

I want to exclude these:

```
InstanceID       : 146788
SqlMessageID     : 0
Message          : The job failed.  The Job was ***invoked by User domain\user***.  The last step to run was step 3 (packagename Pkg).
StepID           : 0
StepName         : (Job outcome)
```

but include these

```
   InstanceID       : 146789
  SqlMessageID     : 0
Message          : The job failed.  The Job was ***invoked by User domain\serviceaccount***.  The last step to run was step 3 (packagename Pkg).
StepID           : 0
StepName         : (Job outcome)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering returned objects based on the message text.

`Get-SqlAgentJobHistory -ServerInstance $SqlServer -OutcomesType Failed -StartRunDate ((Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)) | Where-Object {$_.message -Like "*invoked by User domain\serviceaccount*"}`

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten to update before, but got an answer, same as yours, on other site as November 3, 2018 at 7:52 pm

Answer (score 0):

Solution that has worked for me was suggested by kvprasoon on powershell.org

```
 | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Message -notmacth 'serviceaccount'}
```